# C# NAudio Get audio file duration / Performance

Tags: c#, performance, file, audio, naudio

I'm using NAudio to create a music player that supports playlists. I'm retreiving the duration of each track as follows :

```
return new AudioFileReader(FilePath).TotalTime;
```

But this is a true performance killer when working with many tracks. It takes say 1 second for 15 / 20 audio files. Is there a way to optimize that ? I don't think I can reuse the AudioFile reader object since it doesn't provide any method for that, and I don't know what else I can use to get the audio file duration.

Comment: I'm curious about this too... not really an answer, but since you're storing the playlist items somewhere, maybe store the metadata there too? No need to recompute it for the same file every time the playlist loads. Or, offload it to a separate thread and update asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks i'll consider storing the durations in the playlist file.

Answer (score 2):

You have probably solved this already, but for everyone interested, I would say **Parallelization** would be an option. Usually the I/O process is just very slow in comparison to the CPU being busy. This should take advantage of that.

Change your code that repeatedly calls the length calculation for each track to something like this:

```
        var playTime = new TimeSpan();
        Parallel.ForEach( [yourFileList], file => {
            [...]
            var time = new AudioFileReader(file).TotalTime;
            playTime.Add(time);
            [...]
        });

        bar();
```

Advantage:

- Easy: doesnt need to be in an async Method, usually not much change required
- will automatically spawn multiple tasks of the inner function but wait for everything to finish until bar() is executed (blocking thread).

Disadvantage:

- proper Exception handling is more "difficult"
- cant be cancelled

Answer (score 0):

it depends a lot on the file type. probably for the quickest results, assuming you're not needing to support Windows XP, try using `MediaFoundationReader` instead.